# AWS WS API GW: How can I get the connectionId, if I have proxy integration enabled?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have set up an AWS WS API Gateway that will connect to my nodejs/express backend service which is inside a vpc, for some reason that I don't understand I have a requirement to enable HTTP proxy integration option on all of the WS routes. This would usually not be a problem except for the fact that I can't get a handle on the WS connectionId when it is enabled.

When I first started writing the code I had it uploaded on an ec2 with the GW set to HTTP integration type, I also had defined a request template that defines a connection_id from the $Context object and everything was working smoothly.

My question is what is the purpose of the HTTP proxy integration option (I have looked through AWS's documentation, but it wasn't very helpful to me), and how can I get a handle on the connectionId if I have the HTTP proxy integration option enabled (since I can't find it in the express request object)?

Appreciate any help with this